# Adding and Removing classes by "Vanilla JavaScript" giving Error

Tags: javascript

In a simple example, I am trying to find if a class is present and based on its 'toggling' background via classes in JS. The code is having the problem, can someone help solve it?

```js
function alpha() {
  document.querySelector('button').classList.contains('red') 
    ? (document.querySelector('button').addClass = 'blue'; document.querySelector('button').removeClass = 'red';) 
    : (document.querySelector('button').addClass = 'red'; document.querySelector('button').removeClass = 'blue';)
}
```

```css
.red { background: red; }
.blue { background: blue; }
```

```html
<button onclick="alpha()" class="red">ok</button>
```

Comment: You can use ```classList.add('blue')``` and ```classList.remove('red')```, which should work.

Comment: @Phil - habit from 'react-world' & JSX!

Comment: @gautamits - Pl can you help post running example? It still has issues...

Comment: You're misusing ternary operators. Use something like a switch or if Statement instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the ternary operator. Also you need to use `classList.remove` to remove the class

Now it works

```
function alpha() {
  document.querySelector('button').classList.contains('red') ? 
    (
    document.querySelector('button').classList.add("blue"),
    document.querySelector('button').classList.remove("red") 
    )
  : (
    document.querySelector('button').classList.add("red"),
    document.querySelector('button').classList.remove("blue"))
}
```

Comment: I want to do 2 operations so || (Or operator) is wrong man; this is not what i intended;

Comment: document.querySelector('button').classList.add("blue") That returns undefined. so or is the only way you can execute two things.

Comment: Thanks bro - Both || and , works here. But, I have queries: *Q1* `|| operator says one of 2 options` then how after adding class - 2nd one of remove other class is also working? *Q2* `Does , in a ternary operator does work of ';'` in if-else or otherwise?

Comment: The || works in the way that if the first one returns anything it will terminate and wont even go to the other part.
`document.querySelector('button').classList.add("blue")` does not return anything so, it also executes the other part of ||.
This is not related to ternary operator. It is about the ||, 
Had first part of || would return anything positive then you can never use || to execute two things.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working code as you asked. Please use ternary operators only while using JSX. in vanilla JS, ternary codes make code unreadable.

```js
function alpha(){
  var node = document.querySelector('button');
  if(node.classList.contains('red')){
    node.classList.add('blue'); 
   node.classList.remove('red');
  }
  else{
    node.classList.add('red');
   node.classList.remove('blue');
  }
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener ("click", alpha, false);
```

```css
.red {background: red;}
.blue {background: blue;}
```

```html
<button id="button" class="red">ok</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to do this is use `.classlist.toggle('blue')`, which adds the class, if it isn't on the element, and removes it, if it is.

Note that `button.blue`'s `background:blue` overrides `button`'s `background:red`.

```js
function alpha() {
  document.querySelector('button').classList.toggle('blue') 
}
```

```css
button { background: red; }
button.blue { background: blue; }
```

```html
<button onclick="alpha()">ok</button>
```